# Iterate over arrays of objects in object keys

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

In HandleBars JS I can easily iterate over key values.

```
var context = {
    "object" : {
        "numbers" : [{data : 1}, {data : 2}, {data : 3}, {data : 4}, {data : 5}],
        "letters" : [{data : 'a'}, {data : 'b'}, {data : 'c'}],
        "people" : [{data : 'Linus'}, {data : 'Larry'}, {data : 'Dennis'}, {data : 'Steve'}]
    }
};

{{#each object}}
    <span>{{@key}}</span>
    {{#each this}}
        /*
            LOOP THROUGH EACH ARRAY HERE
            HOW DO I ACCESS THE 'data' KEY?
        */
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Is there anyway to loop through all the array members using the keys or by another method without registering a Handlebars helper?
I would want my output to look something like

```
    numbers
        1 2 3 4 5
    letters
        a b c
    people
        Linus Larry Dennis Steve
```

Comment: Looking for [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)?

Comment: No, I can retrieve the keys just fine using Handlebars

Comment: That's object iteration using just Javascript, this question relate to Handlebars JS templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{#each object}}
    <span>{{@key}}</span>
    {{#each this}}
        {{this.data}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```